# PHP another sorting issue

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

This issue is a little different than the other sorting question I posed a while back.

The sorting starts out in `DESC`.  You can click the header and it will change to `ASC`, but it will not change back to `DESC` when you click the link again.

Here is the sorting code:

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_GET['o'])) {
   $o = $_GET['o'];
   if (escape_data($o)) {
     $sort_order = $o;
     $d = $_GET['d'];
     if ($d == "DESC") {
       $sort_order .= " DESC";
     }
     else {
       $sort_order .= " ASC";
     }
   }
   else{
     $sort_order = $init_sort_order . " " . $asc_or_desc;
     $sort_error = TRUE;
 }
 else{
   $sort_order = $init_sort_order . " " . $asc_or_desc;
 }
 ?>
```

The variable `$o` is the name header (which is a link), and $d seems to be `DESC` or `ASC`.  `$d` and `$o` appear to combine so when it gets to the query, the query will echo out like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT $db_return, MATCH($db_query) AGAINST ('$trimmed' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM $db_table WHERE delete_flag = 'N' and MATCH($db_query) AGAINST ('$trimmed' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY $sort_order";
```

Notice `$sort_order`, which now contains the header as well as `DESC` or `ASC`.

In another file, called `CONFIG.PHP`, I found these variables linked to the sorting feature:

```
 <?php
 $init_sort_order = "relevance"; 
 $asc_or_desc = "DESC";
 ?>
```

This has been frustrating me all day.  I really wanted to have this figured out by now.

Please help.

Comment: Is the other question relevant (if so, link it), or did you just refer to it because "PHP sorting issue" is not accepted as a title?

Comment: You need to post the relevant code surrounding the link that is not switching back to `DESC` as that is the problem not the code you have posted above

Comment: Most likely `$_GET['d']` is not `DESC`, but there is no way to tell by this code.

Comment: @GolezTrol, my apologies. This search is utilizing a "Joe Dolson" search, which is not related to my previous question. My previous question was more of an AJAX question.  I guess this question is a fail.

Answer (score -1):

Why you are appending the $sort_order if you need it ASC or DESC ?

**$sort_order .= " ASC"; should be $asc_or_desc = " ASC";**

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_GET['o'])) {
   $o = $_GET['o'];
   if (escape_data($o)) {
     $sort_order = $o;
     $d = $_GET['d'];
     if ($d == "DESC") {
       //$sort_order .= " DESC";
         $asc_or_desc = " DESC";
     }
     else {
       //$sort_order .= " ASC";
         $asc_or_desc = " ASC";
     }
   }
   else{
     $sort_order = $init_sort_order . " " . $asc_or_desc;
     $sort_error = TRUE;
 }
 else{
   $sort_order = $init_sort_order . " " . $asc_or_desc;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It looks like `$o` contains the field to sort by (the column), to which the sort direction (`$d`) is added. So the concatination seems to make sense.

Comment: Try to use ASC or DESC in a separate variable to be appended later in string.